# 登録可能なドメインのサフィックスリストを参照する方法

Tags: dns

新しいTLDの登場やSLDの追加等クッキーモンスターバグへの対応が複雑さを増していますが、特定のドメインが一般的に登録可能なものかどうか調べる上でMozillaが提供するPublic Suffix Listをリアルタイムに、かつ効率的に参照するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

すでに今のリストは膨大で、世界中で絶え間なく変更されるレジストリ側の手続きを
テキストファイルからキャッチアップしていくのは将来的にも無理がありそうに思えます。

https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat

現在はこのリストを定期的に参照し、ローカルのDBにキャッシュしていますが
まるで/etc/hostsによる名前解決の時代に遡っているような錯覚すら覚えます。

現在のベストプラクティスでは、この問題に対してどのように対処すべきでしょうか？
またその方法論について積極的に議論されているディスカッションフォーラムなどがあれば教えていただければと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Public Suffix Listのサイトを確認する限り、Atomフィードで差分を流しているので、変更はそちらで確認できると思います。

https://github.com/publicsuffix/list/commits/master.atom